# how to slide library image in image view

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am new programming how ever i developing and application i wan`t to access all library image in my image view and slide the image and see it . like and any camera we see all images can any body suggest!

how to implement all library image in my view and slide it i am implementing this but through that i can access only single image.

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
     picker.delegate=self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [_imageview setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In oder to get all photo / assets from the native photo application you can use the Photos Framework. You can find the detailed documentation from this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408